# Understanding python typing: Optional, Callable, Iterable for error handling while reading a JSON file

Tags: python, error-handling

Microsoft python code using RichPath and dpu_utils to load json files. I'm having trouble following what the following code is doing. Is it just returning None if there is an error? I understand that this is a generator and I can call next(tmp=test()).

```
from typing import Any, List, Optional, Iterable, Callable
from collections import OrderedDict
def test( error_handling: Optional[Callable[[str, Exception], None]]=None) -> Iterable[Any]:
    fh = open('ppi/train_graph.json', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')

    try:
        for line in fh:
            try:
                yield json.loads(line, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
            except Exception as e:
                if error_handling is None:
                    raise
                else:
                    error_handling(line, e)
    finally:
        fh.close()
        
gen = test()
```

Comment: No, this function returns a generator object.  It never returns None.

Comment: Anyway, `Callable[[str, Exception], None]` is basically just a function that takes two positional arguments, the first one a string, the other one an Exception, and returns `None`. That is called n any `line` that throws an exception. The result of calling that function isn't returned, so it just skips that line

Comment: okay, so it just skips the line. cool. thanks

Comment: I should have said, "isn't yielde"